# Continuous modification of process.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\xi_n(t)$ is a continuous modification of a process $\omega(t),t\geq 0$ on $[0,n]$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I want to prove that there exists a continuous modification $\xi(t),t\geq 0$ of process $\omega(t)$.

Suppose that $\xi(\omega)(t) = \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \xi_n(\omega)(t)$ $\forall \omega\in\Omega, \forall t\in[0,\infty)$.
Then we have:

$$P\{\xi(t)\neq \omega(t)\} \leq P\left\{ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \xi_n(t) \neq \omega(t) \right\} = 0\ \forall t \in [0,\infty),$$

so $\xi(t)$ is indeed a continuous modification of $\omega(t)$. Is my solution right?

Comment: It does not seem to me that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \xi_n(\omega)(t)$ is well defined. To define it, you could use the fact that the sequence of modifications $\left(\xi_n : [0,n] \to \mathbb{R}\right)_n$ is compatible in the sense that for any $n,m$ $\xi_n, \xi_m$ are indistinguishable on $[0, n\wedge m]$, i.e. except for a negligible set $N$, $\xi_n(\omega)(t) = \xi_m(\omega)(t)$ for all $t \in [0, n\wedge m]$, $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N$, because the continuous modification is unique up to indistinguishability. We can then set $$\xi(t) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \xi_n(t) \mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n]}(t).$$...

Comment: ... then for any $t \in [0, \infty)$ $$P\left[\xi(t) \neq \omega(t)\right] \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} P\left[\xi_n(t) \neq \omega(t)\right] \mathbf{1}_{[n-1, n]}(t) = 0,$$ which shows that $\xi$ is the continuous modification of $\omega$ on $[0,\infty)$.